# ReactiveUI in WPF: RoutedViewHost Can't Resolve View

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, reactiveui

I recently took up the task of learning how to build an application in WPF, and landed on ReactiveUI as my MVVM framework. I am currently trying to practice implementing the Router in my application, and I'm finding that despite following the examples from "You, I, and ReactiveUI", my RoutedViewHost is not displaying a view, and throws the error:

"System.Exception: 'Couldn't find view for 'LearnReactiveUI.ViewModels.StartupViewModel'.'"

Below is the xaml for my main window (ReactiveWindow), and has a RoutedViewHost as its body

```
<rxui:ReactiveWindow x:Class="LearnReactiveUI.Views.MainView"
        xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
        xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:LearnReactiveUI.ViewModels"
        x:TypeArguments="vms:MainViewModel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearnReactiveUI.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <rxui:RoutedViewHost x:Name="routedViewHost"/>
    </Grid>
</rxui:ReactiveWindow>
```

Here is my MainViewModel class, which creates a RoutingState and then navigates to a new StartupViewModel

```
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LearnReactiveUI.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject, IScreen
    {
        private readonly RoutingState routingState;
        public MainViewModel()
        {
           this.routingState = new RoutingState();

           routingState.Navigate.Execute(new StartupViewModel(this));
        }
        public RoutingState Router => this.routingState;
    }
}
```

And finally here is my code-behind for my MainWindow that binds the Router to the RoutedViewHost

```
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using LearnReactiveUI.ViewModels;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;

namespace LearnReactiveUI.Views
{
    public partial class MainView : ReactiveWindow<MainViewModel>
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
                {
                    this
                        .OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.Router, v => v.routedViewHost.Router)
                        .DisposeWith(disposables);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

The code for my Startup view is also very simple. Here is the xaml

```
<rxui:ReactiveUserControl x:Class="LearnReactiveUI.Views.StartupView"
             xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
             xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:LearnReactiveUI.ViewModels"
             x:TypeArguments="vms:StartupViewModel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearnReactiveUI.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Startup" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="72"/>
    </Grid>
</rxui:ReactiveUserControl>
```

And here is the code for the StartupViewModel

```
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LearnReactiveUI.ViewModels
{
    public class StartupViewModel : ReactiveObject, IRoutableViewModel
    {
        private IScreen hostScreen;
        public StartupViewModel(IScreen hostScreen)
        {
            this.hostScreen = hostScreen;
        }
        public string UrlPathSegment => "Startup";
        public IScreen HostScreen => this.hostScreen;

    }
}
```

There is no code in the code behind as there are no properties I am binding to the view yet.

My code compiles and I have verified that it will successfully instantiate a MainView and MainViewModel. I am trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your view and viewModel. Please look at [routing example](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/routing/).

In my opinion, this change in the `MainViewModel` constructor should fix the issue:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    this.routingState = new RoutingState();

    // register view and viewModel
    Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new StartupView(), typeof(IViewFor<StartupViewModel>));

    routingState.Navigate.Execute(new StartupViewModel(this));
}
```

@Glenn Watson mentions an important thing. The `Locator` setup should be done in a bootstrap-like class to allow multiple platform coding and to not break DI. You should look at this when you learn the basics.

Comment: Generally best that view registration is not in view models. Won't allow multiple platform coding and also breaks the DI concept.

Comment: @GlennWatson thank you for the comment, I totally agree. I made an update of my answer. I suggested minimal code changes to not be overwhelmed by the amount of information.

Comment: Thank you both! I was having trouble with the Splat Locator since I was trying to register my view as a ReactiveUserControl rather than as an IViewFor. I had removed the code as it wasn't working. Still not sure why it throws an error with ReactiveUserControl since it inherits from IViewFor, but I'm happy to have a solution! Next step is to build a bootstrapper :)